# Riak database and spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, riak

Is possible to use Riak as database with spring mvc?

If yes where can I find some simple examples?

And expect for riak and spring, do I need additional programs for reading and writing to/from the database ?

And last question what is hadoop used for?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop

Comment: Why down voting my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC has nothing to do with any database. It's a framework for building your presentation layer which should talk to some business layer which in turn should make use of some data access layer (here's where you get concerned about database persistence).

There is a Spring Data project which provides some common abstractions which can be backed by all kinds of databases. And there seems to be a [Spring Data Riak](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue/tree/master/spring-data-riak) module inside the spring-data-keyvalue project, which you may find useful.

Hadoop, at its core, is a distributed file system which allows you to perform distributed computations on your (possibly huge) data (using the Map/Reduce paradigm or the more general YARN framework).

Comment: Thank you for description.
But how can I connect my spring project whit Riak. I use mysql and the connection is by some xml file. Is there something similar with Riak?